# How to serialize objects with json

Tags: python, json

Both the `Child` and `Parent` classes inherit from Python dictionary:

```
import json 

class Child(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Parent(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

parent = Parent(child = Child())

print type(parent['child'])
```

prints:

```
<class '__main__.Child'>
```

After performing the serialization and de-serialization using `json.dumps` and `json.loads` the `Parent['child']` becomes a regular dictionary:

```
dumped = json.dumps(parent)
loaded = json.loads(dumped)
parent_2 = Parent(**loaded)
print type(parent_2['child'])
```

prints:

```
<type 'dict'>
```

Question: how to make sure that after the serialization, the `parent_2['child']` is the instance of the `Child` and not a regular Python dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loads` makes a dictionary and that's that. After some trial and error I found it out. (Note: It looks like you are using legacy Python so the syntax may need some tweaking from this solution.)

```
import json


class Child(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Parent(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(**kwargs)


parent = Parent(child=Child())

print(type(parent['child']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dumped = json.dumps(parent)
    loaded = json.loads(dumped)
    parent_2 = Parent(child=Child(**loaded)) # Changed how you call Parent
    print(type(parent_2['child']))
```

Without calling the args of `Parent` with a `dict` initialized as `Child`, we can have no expectation of detecting the `Child` type **unless you add additional logic to detect the type.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use *pickle*. It can be dangerous to unpickle unknown pickled objects(as they can be malicious).

read documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html
as it contains more information.

```
import pickle
class Foo:
    attr = 'A class attribute'


with open('pickle_class.pk','wb') as f:
         pickle.dump(Foo,f)   

# we open the file for reading
with open('pickle_class.pk','rb') as f:

    Bar = pickle.load(f)

# Test if they are the same.
assert Bar==Foo,'Not the Same'
```

You can also compress.

```
import bz2
import pickle

with bz2.BZ2File('pickled_class', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(Foo, s)
```

In some cases, as using multithreading and lambda, *dill*, third-party module, can be handy as pickle throws

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x111d0a7b8>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

The flow and danger(unpickling malicious software) are the same:

```
import dill

class Foo:
    attr = 'A class attribute'

with open('pickle_class.pk','wb') as f:
    dill.dump(Foo,f)
```

Read dill documentation: https://pypi.org/project/dill/

**N.B: Never-ever load unknown pickled file**

Comment: Clean and convenient use of pickle with appropriate warning -- I think this solution is better than mine but I will leave mine up for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/). It seems to do the trick;

```
import json
import jsonpickle

class Child(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Parent(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = Parent(child=Child())
    dumped = jsonpickle.encode(parent)
    loaded = jsonpickle.decode(dumped)
    parent_2 = Parent(**loaded)
    print(type(parent_2['child']))

<class '__main__.Child'>
```

Note; for this to work, the Json will have information about the original object graph so that it can be restored.

```
('{"py/object": "__main__.Parent", "child": {"py/object": "__main__.Child", '
 '"__dict__": {}}, "__dict__": {}}')
```